# Polymer: Buttonclick triggers parent container click-event

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to develop a collapsible list based on Google Inbox in Polymer.

I've created a list of polymer-elements, where each element is a *paper-material* with an *iron-collapse* inside.
The *iron-collapse* contains data and a couple of *paper-button*s.

I need to show/hide the `<iron-collapse>` element, when clicking the parent *paper-material*.

This works really well, but unfortunately that event also fires after clicking a *paper-button* e.g. **Send-Button** inside the *iron-collapse*.

I tried adding *event.stopPropagation()* to the child's button handler, but the *iron-collapse* still collapses, when clicking the button.

Any ideas?

Code for parent container:

```
<paper-material id="papercontainer" elevation="1" class="container padded" animated style="border-radius:4px;">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="container flex-start-justified">
            <div class="flexchild">
                <h4 class="smaller-margin">Bill Gates</h4>
                <p class="smaller-margin">bill@gates.com</p>
                <p class="paper-font-caption smaller-margin">Date received: 01/01/2015</p>
            </div>
            <p>
                    <paper-button raised on-click="send">Send</paper-button>
            </p>
        </div>

<!--Code for iron-collapse (child): -->

        <div class="container flex-horizontal">
                <iron-collapse id="collapse" class="flexchild">
                    <div class="flexchild collapse-content" style="margin-top:10px;">
                         <paper-button>Edit Mail</paper-button>

                     </div>
                 </iron-collapse>
        </div>

    </div>
</paper-material>
```

Javascript:

```
Polymer({           
        is: 'zapytania-result-element2',

        toggle: function() {
            this.$.collapse.toggle();
        },

        listeners: {
            'tap': 'regularTap'
        },

        regularTap: function(e) {
            console.log('toggle iron-collapse');
            if(this.$.collapse.opened) {
                this.$.collapse.hide();
                this.$.papercontainer.elevation = 1;
            } else {
                this.$.collapse.show();
                this.$.papercontainer.elevation = 5;
            }
        },
       send: function() {
           sendMail();
       }
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: I have provided some code. Generally speaking the iron-collapse shows/hides, when it is clicked, but also when Send button inside is clicked. How to circumvent this?

Comment: Doesn't looks like iron-collapse listens for click events. Are you sure you don't call `toggle` yourself?. Where is `toggle()` called from?

Comment: I have figured it out, see answer below. Thank you for your help, sir.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the Events Tutorial from 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html

Per my understanding 'tap' makes the whole element listen for the tap event.

After removing that handler and assigning my own on-click event handler to the parent paper-material container and calling e.stopPropagation() at the end of my child's button event it works.